# Adding a new page to PDF and create signature with iText 7

Tags: java, pdf, adobe, signature, itext7

For a project I have to digitally sign PDFs on an additionally created page by multiple people in a workflow. To realize this we're using the iText 7 libraries with following code, based on Bruno Lowagie's examples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, XMPException {
    String path = "F:/Java/keystores/testPdfSign";
    char[] pass = "test".toCharArray();

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "SunJSSE");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(path), pass);
    String alias = "";
    Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
    while (alias.equals("tester")==false && aliases.hasMoreElements()) 
    {
        alias = aliases.nextElement();
    }
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pass);
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
    PDFSign app = new PDFSign();
    app.sign(SRC, DEST, chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1, "SunJSSE", PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test", "Test", null, null, null, 0);
}

public void sign(String src, String dest,
                 Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk,
                 String digestAlgorithm, String provider, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard subfilter,
                 String reason, String location,
                 Collection<ICrlClient> crlList,
                 IOcspClient ocspClient,
                 ITSAClient tsaClient,
                 int estimatedSize)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, XMPException {
    // Creating the reader and the signer

    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST+"_temp"));
    if (initial == true)
    {
        document.addNewPage();
    }
    int pageCount = document.getNumberOfPages();
    document.close();
    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(new PdfReader(DEST+"_temp"), new FileOutputStream(DEST), true); 
    // Creating the appearance
    if (initial == true)
    {
        signer.setCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING_AND_ANNOTATIONS);
    }
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance()
            .setReason(reason)
            .setLocation(location)
            .setReuseAppearance(false);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 400, 100, 100);
    appearance
            .setPageRect(rect)
            .setPageNumber(pageCount);
    appearance.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION);
    signer.setFieldName(signer.getNewSigFieldName());
    // Creating the signature
    IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
    ProviderDigest digest = new ProviderDigest(provider);
    signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize, subfilter);

}
```

This results in an invalid signature in the new signed version of the PDF, as Adobe Acrobat Reader says it has been edited after signing. Surprisingly when I open the file in Foxit Reader it says it hasn't been modified and is valid.

Also what I tried was to leave out the first step of adding a new page and just sign on the last page of the original document, then the signature is valid in Adobe Reader, but no solution for my situation, as an extra page is a must have.
The other thing I tried was not setting the certificationLevel to `CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING_AND_ANNOTATIONS`, but just leaving it at the default `NOT_CERTIFIED`, this way I also had a valid signature on a new page, but this is not a solution either, because it won't let me add any additional signatures later on.

Does someone have an idea what could be the reason for Adobe Reader rating the signature as invalid and/or has a solution to this problem?

Thanks in Advance

David

Comment: Can you show your original pdf? Your description sounds like it already is signed.

Comment: I tried with different pdfs, all unsigned, so that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your issue but it results in a `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SHA1 for provider SunJSSE`. Indeed, your use of the provider `SunJSSE` hardly makes sense.

Comment: I changed your code to use "BC" instead of "SunJSSE" and registering the BouncyCastle provider up front. Running it now results in a proper signature, "Document has not been modified since it was certified".

Comment: First of all thanks for your help! Unfortunately changing the provider to BouncyCastle results in the same problem for me, could you let me see your code? Also could you maybe explain why using `SunJSSE` doesn't make sense?

Comment: Confer my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In short

I could not reproduce the OP's issue. Running his code (with slight adaptions to local circumstances) resulted in a `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SHA1 for provider SunJSSE`. Having replaced the provider argument "SunJSSE" to the `sign` call with "BC", on the other hand, the code creates a properly certified PDF.

#### The adapted code

I usually examine code from stackoverflow in the form of a JUnit test; this implies a few changes. Furthermore, the OP's code contained a number of variables which were referenced but not defined; these had to be given a definition. Finally i load the file to sign from a resource as stream, not from the file system as file.

Thus:

```
final static File RESULT_FOLDER = new File("target/test-outputs", "signature");

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception
{
    RESULT_FOLDER.mkdirs();
    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);
}

@Test
public void testSignLikeXinDHA() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, XMPException
{
    String path = "keystores/demo-rsa2048.p12";
    char[] pass = "demo-rsa2048".toCharArray();

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "SunJSSE");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(path), pass);
    String alias = "";
    Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
    while (alias.equals("demo") == false && aliases.hasMoreElements())
    {
        alias = aliases.nextElement();
    }
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pass);
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);

    try ( InputStream resource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mkl/testarea/itext7/content/test.pdf"))
    {
        sign(resource, new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "test_XinDHA_signed_initial.pdf").getAbsolutePath(),
                chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA1, /*"SunJSSE"*/"BC", PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, "Test", "Test",
                null, null, null, 0, true);
    }
}

public void sign(InputStream src, String dest, Certificate[] chain, PrivateKey pk, String digestAlgorithm,
        String provider, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard subfilter, String reason, String location,
        Collection<ICrlClient> crlList, IOcspClient ocspClient, ITSAClient tsaClient, int estimatedSize,
        boolean initial)
        throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, XMPException
{
    // Creating the reader and the signer

    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest + "_temp"));
    if (initial == true)
    {
        document.addNewPage();
    }
    int pageCount = document.getNumberOfPages();
    document.close();
    PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(new PdfReader(dest + "_temp"), new FileOutputStream(dest), true);
    // Creating the appearance
    if (initial == true)
    {
        signer.setCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING_AND_ANNOTATIONS);
    }
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance().setReason(reason).setLocation(location)
            .setReuseAppearance(false);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 400, 100, 100);
    appearance.setPageRect(rect).setPageNumber(pageCount);
    appearance.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION);
    signer.setFieldName(signer.getNewSigFieldName());
    // Creating the signature
    IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
    ProviderDigest digest = new ProviderDigest(provider);
    signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize, subfilter);
}
```

*([AddPageAndSign.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/AddPageAndSign.java))*

#### Running the code

I ran the code using a fairly recent Oracle Java 8 with Unlimited Strength Java<sup>TM</sup> Cryptography Extension Policy Files, BouncyCastle 1.49, and iText either in version 7.0.0 or 7.0.1-SNAPSHOT (the current development branch).

(Definitively use an Oracle Java as downloaded from their web site, some variants of the Oracle JDK (supplied by some Linux distributions) contains changes in the security providers which can break your code.)

Running the code using the provider argument "SunJSSE" to the `sign` call results in

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SHA1 for provider SunJSSE
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:87)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:206)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:698)
    at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:227)
    at com.itextpdf.signatures.SignUtils.getMessageDigest(SignUtils.java:134)
    at com.itextpdf.signatures.DigestAlgorithms.getMessageDigest(DigestAlgorithms.java:182)
    at com.itextpdf.signatures.ProviderDigest.getMessageDigest(ProviderDigest.java:69)
    at com.itextpdf.signatures.SignUtils.getMessageDigest(SignUtils.java:127)
    at com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSigner.signDetached(PdfSigner.java:528)
    at mkl.testarea.itext7.signature.AddPageAndSign.sign(AddPageAndSign.java:125)
    at mkl.testarea.itext7.signature.AddPageAndSign.testSignLikeXinDHA(AddPageAndSign.java:81)
```

Running the code using the provider argument "BC" to the `sign` call results in a properly certified PDF with the signature visualization on an extra page:

[image: Screenshot of signature panel]

#### Why using SunJSSE doesn't make sense

The exception I get with the "SunJSSE" provider actually is not surprising as that provider does not provide a SHA1 algorithm.

According to [its documentation by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider), it provides no MessageDigest algorithm as such at all, merely in combination as a signature algorithm (SHA1withRSA).

Thus, the `IExternalSignature` defined in `sign` as

```
IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
```

will work because here SHA1withRSA will be used, but the `ProviderDigest` defined there as

```
ProviderDigest digest = new ProviderDigest(provider);
```

will fail because it attempts to use the message digest algorithm SHA1.

#### As an aside

You use SHA1. As this message digest algorithm is less and less trusted in the context of signature creation, that is not a good idea. I would advise switching to an algorithm of the SHA2 famaily.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer to my problem and the explanation concerning SunJSSE. I'm now using BouncyCastle, but that alone didn't solve the problem. What I also had to adjust a little bit was the creation of the `PdfDocument`, now using StampingProperties set to appendMode:

`StampingProperties properties = new StampingProperties();
properties.useAppendMode();
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(SRC), new PdfWriter(DEST+"_temp"), properties);`

Comment: But I don't really get why this is needed, because the PdfDocument is only used to add the page and then writes a file and we only sign that resulting file then, so the `PdfSigner` object doesn't know the original document.

Comment: Does it probably contain a usage rights signature? Unless your original document is already signed, the described behavior does not make sense. And using a truly unsigned source PDF I could not reproduce your issue.

Comment: No, I tried different PDFs and for all it was the same. I know the behavior does not make sense, but that got it working for me.